# Datascroller and sortOrder on rich:extendedDataTable

Tags: jsf, datatable, richfaces, datascroller

I had a problem on a Jsf page.
The datascroller didn't change pagination of the dataTable clicking on a number of page (still stay on the first page of the pagination).

- Richfaces : 3.3.2.SR1
- Jsf : 1.2
- JBoss 5.0.1

This code doesn't change the pagination :

```
<rich:extendedDataTable id="tableDataTable" value="#{beanController.listTableDataModel}" 
    var="tableItem" selectionMode="single"
    rows="3" width="150px" height="100px" selection="#{beanController.tableSelection}">

    <rich:column sortBy="#{tableItem.code}" width="150px" label="#{msg.table}">
        <h:outputText value="#{tableItem.code}" />
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column sortBy="#{tableItem.code}" width="150px" label="#{msg.table}">
        <h:outputText value="#{tableItem.code}" />
    </rich:column>
</rich:extendedDataTable>
<rich:datascroller id="tableDataScroller" align="center" for="tableDataTable" renderIfSinglePage="false" />
```

I solved it defining the `sortOrder` attribute.
This works fine (only one difference : `sortOrder="ASCENDING"` on a column):

```
<rich:extendedDataTable id="tableDataTable" value="#{beanController.listTableDataModel}" 
    var="tableItem" selectionMode="single"
    rows="3" width="150px" height="100px" selection="#{beanController.tableSelection}">

    <rich:column sortBy="#{tableItem.code}" width="150px" label="#{msg.table}" sortOrder="ASCENDING">
        <h:outputText value="#{tableItem.code}" />
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column sortBy="#{tableItem.code}" width="150px" label="#{msg.table}">
        <h:outputText value="#{tableItem.code}" />
    </rich:column>
</rich:extendedDataTable>
<rich:datascroller id="tableDataScroller" align="center" for="tableDataTable" renderIfSinglePage="false" />
```

The question is Why do we have to define the sortOrder to correct the datatable pagination using datascroller ?
Any idea ?

**Edit** : DataProvider Code

```
public class BeanDataProvider implements DataProvider<Bean> {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3539248649798786324L;

    public BeanDataProvider() {
    }

    public BeanDataProvider(ArrayList<Bean> beans) {
        this.beans = beans;
    }

    private List<Bean> beans;


    public Bean getItemByKey(Object paramObject) {
        Bean resultat = null;
        for (Bean bean : this.getBeans()) {
            if (bean.getIdentifiant().equals(paramObject)) {
                resultat = bean;
                break;
            }
        }
        return resultat;
    }


    public List<Bean> getItemsByRange(int paramInt1, int paramInt2) {
        return this.getBeans().subList(paramInt1, paramInt2);
    }


    public Object getKey(Bean paramT) {
        return paramT.getIdentifiant();
    }


    public int getRowCount() {
        return this.getBeans().size();
    }


    public List<Bean> getBeans() {
        if (beans == null) {
            beans = new ArrayList<Bean>();
        }
        return beans;
    }


    public void setbeans(List<Bean> beans) {
        this.beans = beans;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your DataProvider implementation? Is it possible to paste a code snippet in the question?

Comment: @Andrey: See the edit. What are you thinking about ?

Comment: @Java See the begining of the post : Richfaces 3.3.2.SR1 (I'll try with 3.3.3.Final), Jsf 1.2, JBoss 5.0.1. which other version do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug in RichFaces:

> [TableSorting - Built-in - pages cannot be switched by
>   DataScroller](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-8096)
>
> When clicked on the numbered page (e.g. 2) in the initial state, page
>   wasn't switched.
>
> The table was re-rendered well after clicking on the sorted-column's
>   header.

Upgrading to 3.3.3.Final should help.

Regarding `ExtendedTableDataModel`:

It **is** available in 3.3.3.Final (`org.richfaces.model.ExtendedTableDataModel` in richfaces-impl-3.3.3.Final.jar).
And it is also available in the documentation: http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/3.3.X/3.3.3.Final/en/apidoc_impl/ (../apidoc_impl/ is used for richfaces-impl, ../apidoc/ is used for richfaces-ui).

It is **not** available in RF4. In RF4 explore these classes:

```
org.richfaces.model.ArrangeableState
org.ajax4jsf.model.ExtendedDataModel
org.richfaces.model.ArrangeableModel
```

**UPDATE:**

Use `ExtendedTableDataModifiableModel` instead of `ExtendedTableDataModel`:

```
new ExtendedTableDataModifiableModel(dataProvider);
```

Or even better (when list is used as a data source as in your case):

```
new ListDataModel(list);
```

Comment: I upgraded to 3.3.3.Final, but the problem is still here. I still can correct it adding the sortOrder on the column. For information, I now using : `<dependency>
   <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
   <artifactId>richfaces-ui</artifactId>
   <version>3.3.3.Final</version>
  </dependency>
 
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.richfaces.framework</groupId>
   <artifactId>richfaces-impl</artifactId>
   <version>3.3.3.Final</version>
  </dependency>`

Comment: @Jean-Charles Have you tried using another table model implementation (refer to UPDATE section)?

Comment: I'm doing it... But I've priority works which stop me in the development. For the time being, using ListDataModel, I can't retrieve the selected line, `getRowData()` returns null. how to declare `rich:extendedDataTable` and have the row in `getRowData()`?

Comment: I give you the bounty before it'll expire but the solution isn't implemented yet. I'm not eable to get the selected value without use a dataprovider. Can you help me how to use ListDataModel and extendedDataTable? More, can you tell me why I don't have to use ExtendedTableDataModel?

Comment: @Jean-Charles ExtendedTableDataModel has some strange implementation of walk method. And also there is a tricky implementation of the richDataTable component. It wraps dataModel with ExtendedTableDataModifiableModel in case you have sort columns, otherwise it passes your dataTable as is.

Comment: I would also try doing in such way: new ExtendedTableDataModifiableModel(yourDataProvider); and also such way: new SequenceDataModel(yourDataModel);

Comment: @Jean-Charles Hm, I have reproduced the issue on my environment. No of my suggestions helps :(. Will dig it further.

Comment: Even in 3.3.3: With ExtendedTableDataModel the datascroller doesn't work. With ExtendedTableDataModifiableModel ou ListDataModel, I can't get the object selected. Why dataProvider interact with datascroller? If you can make ListDataModel  workable, I'll be the best solution. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Jean-Charles dataProvider does not interact with datascroller. Actual lifecycle is as following: datascroller invokes setFirst() method on dataTable component, then dataTable invokes walk() method on dataModel. Problem is that ExtendedTableDataModel caches data, and returns that data regardless of Range parameter passed.

Comment: Also selection works good for both ExtendedTableDataModifiableModel and ListDataModel. If you need ExtendedTableDataModel for some reason do so: new ExtendedTableDataModifiableModel(yourExtendedTableDataModel, null);

Answer (score 1):

Tested your code using richfaces 3.3.3 and it works fine .The pagination can changed in both cases. So I think the sortOrder  and the datatable pagination do not have relationship to affect each others.

And I found the [release note of RichFaces - Version 3.3.3.BETA1](https://issues.jboss.org/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=12310341&version=12314119) has some bug fixes about the `rich:datascroller` . Perhaps you can upgrade to richfaces 3.3.3 in your DEV environment to see if the problems are still there.

Comment: "the sortOrder and the datatable pagination do not have relationship to affect each others." I agree, this is why I posted ;) Otherwise, I'll update and see. Thanks for your tips

Comment: Changing to 3.3.3.Final, I have problem with unresolved ExtendedTableDataModel. I've found out the ExtendedTableDataModel class in 
[latest_3_3_X](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/apidoc_impl/org/richfaces/model/ExtendedTableDataModel.html), 
but not in [3.3.3.Final](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/3.3.X/3.3.3.Final/en/apidoc/). 

Is this class removed in 3.3.3 ?

Comment: Finding ExtendedTableDataModel in [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/3.3.X/3.3.3.Final/en/apidoc_impl/), but not in the jar... Is this class removed in 3.3.3 jar ?

Comment: @Jean-Charles I can find ExtendedTableDataModel in the `richfaces-impl-3.3.3.Final.jar`

Comment: See my comment on Andrey answer to know that the upgrade doesn't correct the bug. Any other idea or recommendation?